# Referring to a variable one report region from another

Tags: oracle-apex

:APEX$ROW_SELECTOR is tabular report region one

I want to select records from "Table" where :APEX$ROW_SELECTOR = 'X' as the source for the report in region 2 on the same page. The report returns no data

select * from table where :APEX$ROW_SELECTOR = 'X'

Comment: You have a tabular form region and another report region. In the report region you want to show records associated with the selected record record in the tabular form region? Or do you want to show the selected records from the tabular form in the report region? What's the reason for this?

Comment: I want to show the selected records from the tabular report form in other regions based on the records selected in the first region. The reason is to allow sorting/selection based on user input allowing  subsequent edit/add delete activity

Answer (score 0):

:APEX$ROW_SELECTOR = 'X' only works when you post the page  and only in the context of a process or validation or computation that is set to run for each row of a tabular form.

Your requirement seems to call for javascript.

I have a long document explaining this I need to post somewhere but the meat of the solution is as follows.

1. Create a page item to store the selected record key value(s)
2. Create a dynamic action that listens for clicks on the checkboxes and sets the checked values into the page item

e.g. if the row selector checkbox is column 1 then trigger it by change to the JQuery selector `$("input[name='f01']")`

and as an action have it run this javascript code

```
var checkedVals;
$("input[name='f01']:checked").each( 
    function() { 
       checkedVals += ':' + this.value;
    } 
);  
$s('PXX_LOOKUP_KEY', checkedVals); // use the name of your page item from step 1
```

3.Create a dynamic action to refresh each child report triggered by a change to the page item value

4.Create filters for child reports to read this page item value (e.g. deal with multiple values) and set the page item as one of the items to post when the report is refreshed